# Bootstrap Modal wont show on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap modal that on click just won't show up.

I have tried using v-show and v-if and also just the $("edit_user_password").modal("show"); but nothing will work

Import happens here:

```
import EditPassword from "@/components/modals/edit_password.vue";
```

Register Component:

```
 components: {
    EditPassword
  },
```

Then I use it in the code here:

```
<EditPassword v-show="this.password_modal"></EditPassword>
```

Then an on-click event on a button:

```
<button @click="update_password()" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Edit Password</button>
```

Then it hits this method here:

```
update_password() {
      console.log('Im clicking i promise');
      this.password_modal = true;
      $("edit_user_password").modal("show");
    }
```

The modal looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="modal fade" id="edit_user_password" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Update Password</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="password">Update Password</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              v-model="password"
              class="form-control"
              id="password"
              placeholder="Create new password"
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      password: ""
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm just sat staring at the code now and can't see why it's not working. If anyone has any suggestions I would be grateful.

Comment: i think u forget to add # when u select id, it should be $("#edit_user_password").modal("show");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `#` sign in your selector :

```
update_password() {
  console.log('Im clicking i promise');
  this.password_modal = true;
  $("#edit_user_password").modal("show");
}
```